# How to convert coordinates to a shapefile

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

i have the below posted coordinates but in wkt formate and i want to write to a file as shapefile.when i run the code i receive the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

after placing some logs for debugging, i found that, the methond `bindPolygonCoordinates` returns nothing
please let me know how correctly export coordinates to a shapefile.

**code**

```
def extractLonLatFromPolygonInWKTFor(polygonInWKT):
lons = []
lats = []
s = polygonInWKT.replace("POLYGON","")
s = s.replace("((","")
s = s.replace("))","")
s = s.strip()
lonsLats = s.split(",")
for i in range (0,len(lonsLats)):
    lonLat = lonsLats[i].strip()
    lonLat = lonLat.split(" ")
    lons.append(float(lonLat[0]))
    lats.append(float(lonLat[1]))
return lons,lats

def bindPolygonCoordinates(longitudeValuesArray, latitudeValuesArray):
return Polygon(zip(longitudeValuesArray, latitudeValuesArray))

def buildGeoDataFrameForGeometry(geometry):
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
return gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[geometry])

lons,lats = extractLonLatFromPolygonInWKTFor(fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326)
boundingPolygonGeometry = bindPolygonCoordinates(lons, lats)#returns nothing
boundingGeometryAsGDF = buildGeoDataFrameForGeometry(boundingPolygonGeometry)
```

**coords**:

```
fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))

lonsLats:['6.741879696309871 51.08423775429969', '6.742907378503366 51.08158745820981', '6.746964018740842 51.08233499299334', '6.746152690693346 51.08440763989611', '6.741879696309871 51.08423775429969']
```

Comment: Since you mention shapely in the tags, why not use [shapely.wkt.loads](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.wkt.loads) to parse the WKT? Also, please fix your indentation. And provide a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: paste your code into a jupyter notebook and it won't begin to work. **fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326** no idea what the value is and indentation won't pass PEP 8

Comment: @RobRaymond would you please have a look again, i added the required coordinates as you requested

Comment: @TurePålsson would you please tell me how wkt.loads would help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as per other comment, use `shapely.wky.loads()`
- no need to hand code parsing standard format
- generating a *.shp* file is then done by **geopandas**

```
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path

fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326 = "POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))"

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("shape_dir")
if not f.is_dir(): f.mkdir()
f = f.joinpath("shape.shp")
gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shapely.wkt.loads(fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326)]).to_file(str(f))
```

Comment: execuse me, but i want it as shape file .shp!!

Comment: ok updated as requested

Comment: appreciate it. i will acknowledge once tested

Comment: would it work for points as well or only for polygons?

Comment: @LetsamrIt https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/io.html saves all geometry to file.  https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#well-known-formats works with points, polygons, ...

Comment: would you please help me find answer to this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672411/how-to-find-distance-between-two-geo-data-frames