# How to find distance between two geo data frames

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

i would like to find the distance between two geodata-frames as shown below in the code.
the code posted below provide different distances values then those i get from postgis database.by visualising distances on qgis, the distances from the database postgis is more realistic and reliable than the ones i get from the below posted code.
please let me know how to correctly find the distance between two geodata-frames.

**code**

```
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    #  Polygon([(4.338074,50.848677), (4.344961,50.833264), (4.366227,50.840809), (4.367945,50.852455), (4.346693,50.858306)])
     'Latitude': [ 51.08423775429969, 51.08158745820981, 51.08233499299334, 51.08440763989611,51.08423775429969],
     'Longitude': [6.741879696309871, 6.742907378503366, 6.746964018740842, 6.746152690693346, 6.741879696309871]

 })
 gdfPoly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({
     'Latitude': [51.13297272331544],
     'Longitude': [6.692247842659104]
 })
 gdfPoint = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, crs=crs,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Longitude, df2.Latitude))
print("{0}".format(gdfPoint.distance(gdfPoly)))
```

**updated results**:

```
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:14.9634941931567
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.6916900697392245 51.132691895123486)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.6916900697392245]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.132691895123486]
dist:0    84.684914
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
dtype: float64
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:0.0
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.69226128514392 51.13270317349424)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.69226128514392]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13270317349424]
dist:0    51.996894
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
dtype: float64
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:0.0
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.69240408905273 51.13270599265131)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.69240408905273]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13270599265131]
dist:0    45.68055
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
dtype: float64
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:27.9534455951444
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.691551748111223 51.13259922519638)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.691551748111223]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13259922519638]
dist:0    90.195441
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
dtype: float64
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:19.7325568769629
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.691694551628079 51.13260204521571)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.691694551628079]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13260204521571]
dist:0    80.7357
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
dtype: float64
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:0.0
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.692265765926083 51.1326133235505)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692265765926083]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.1326133235505]
dist:0    45.281294
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
dtype: float64
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:0.0
polygonAsWKT:POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692790084436616, 6.6918971115756305, 6.6922145189906725, 6.6926758177672, 6.692650425173997, 6.692430356032901, 6.692790084436616]
buildDataFrameFromPolygonAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.13237486727857, 51.132725423664596, 51.13301489625002, 51.13291397940796, 51.1327121450621, 51.132520932762816, 51.13237486727857]
pointAsWKT:POINT(6.692408569558222 51.132616142698566)
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.longitudes:[6.692408569558222]
buildDataFrameFromPointAsWKTFor.latitudes:[51.132616142698566]
dist:0    37.860682
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
dtype: float64
```

**update-1**

for the below posted code, i get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'estimate_utm_crs'
```

Geopandas version is '0.10.2'

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry, json
import shapely.wkt

crs = {"init": "epsg:4326"}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        #  Polygon([(4.338074,50.848677), (4.344961,50.833264), (4.366227,50.840809), (4.367945,50.852455), (4.346693,50.858306)])
        "Latitude": [
            51.13237486727857,
            51.132725423664596,
            51.13301489625002,
            51.13291397940796,
            51.1327121450621,
            51.132520932762816,
            51.13237486727857
            
        ],
        "Longitude": [
            6.692790084436616,
            6.6918971115756305,
            6.6922145189906725,
            6.6926758177672,
            6.692650425173997,
            6.692430356032901,
            6.692790084436616
        ],
    }
)
gdfPoly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Latitude": [51.133239453736344], "Longitude": [6.692091594420977]})
gdfPoint = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df2, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Longitude, df2.Latitude)
)

# finally distance, taking into account CRS in metres
dist = gdfPoint.to_crs(gdfPoint.estimate_utm_crs()).distance(
    gdfPoly.to_crs(gdfPoly.estimate_utm_crs())
)
print(dist)
```

**update-1**

for the following polygon and point

```
POLYGON((6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857,6.6918971115756305 51.132725423664596,6.6922145189906725 51.13301489625002,6.6926758177672 51.13291397940796,6.692650425173997 51.1327121450621,6.692430356032901 51.132520932762816,6.692790084436616 51.13237486727857))
POINT(6.692091594420977 51.133239453736344)
```

the distance should be:26.4203162027475
but i get 107.89036

**update-2**

the following code provide distance equal to 107.890471.when i visualised both of the polygon and the point i as wkt in online wkt viewer, the point is so close to the polygon
please let me know what causes this error in distance reading.

```
rs = {"init": "epsg:4326"}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        #  Polygon([(4.338074,50.848677), (4.344961,50.833264), (4.366227,50.840809), (4.367945,50.852455), (4.346693,50.858306)])
        "Latitude": [
            51.13237486727857,
            51.132725423664596,
            51.13301489625002,
            51.13291397940796,
            51.1327121450621,
            51.132520932762816,
            51.13237486727857
            
        ],
        "Longitude": [
            6.692790084436616,
            6.6918971115756305,
            6.6922145189906725,
            6.6926758177672,
            6.692650425173997,
            6.692430356032901,
            6.692790084436616
        ],
    }
)
gdfPoly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Latitude": [51.133239453736344], "Longitude": [6.692091594420977]})
gdfPoint = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df2, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Longitude, df2.Latitude)
)

# finally distance, taking into account CRS in metres
dist = gdfPoint.to_crs(32632).distance(
    gdfPoly.to_crs(25832)
)
print(dist)
```

Comment: @RobRaymond yes, in kilometers or in meters please

Comment: thanks, i will acknowledge once tested.

Comment: this question cannot be answered.  have put > 8 hours into this.  This is training and consulting not an SO question

Comment: question is made up of answers I have provided,  but keep on being broken by ongoing incorrect coding and misunderstanding of geometric concepts

Comment: What distance are you trying to find? 
1. The distance between the point `df2` and the closest point in data frame `df1`? 
2. The distance between the point `df2` and the closest point on the outline of `df1`?

Comment: @ThijsRuigrok for update-2 abovr, the distance from df2 to df1, it should give me the distance to the nearest edge of the polygon composed of the coordinates as shown in df.i hope it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this following was missing in the code:

```
    gdfPoly2 = gpd.GeoSeries([shapely.geometry.Polygon(gdfPoly.geometry)], crs=crs)
```

**code**

```
crs = {"init": "epsg:25832"}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        #  Polygon([(4.338074,50.848677), (4.344961,50.833264), (4.366227,50.840809), (4.367945,50.852455), (4.346693,50.858306)])
        "Latitude": [
            1003060.89945681,
            1003170.95198635,
            1003781.73122161,
            1003694.55868486,
            1003060.89945681
        ],
        "Longitude": [
            5622486.93624152,
            5622079.52632924,
            5622126.00418918,
            5622444.73987453,
            5622486.93624152
        ],
    }
)
gdfPoly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Latitude": [1003010.44704936], "Longitude": [5622524.15909579]})
gdfPoint = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df2, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Longitude, df2.Latitude)
)

gdfPoly2 = gpd.GeoSeries([shapely.geometry.Polygon(gdfPoly.geometry)], crs=crs)

dist = gdfPoint.to_crs(25832).distance(
    gdfPoly2.to_crs(25832)
)
print("dist: {0}".format(dist))
```